# Select into #TempTable

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have something like the following scenario

```
Select x, y, z
from mytable
where x = 1

UNION

Select x, y, z
from mytable2
where x = 1
```

I would like to put the results into a #TempTable and then create a Pivot of the results into #TempTable2

I have tried

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM (
Select x, y, z
from mytable
where x = 1

UNION

Select x, y, z
from mytable2
where x = 1
)
```

But it get Incorrect syntax near ')'
I've forgotten all the other variations I have made but none of them have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an alias to the derived table. Here I use X because I'm imaginative

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM 
   (
   Select x, y, z
   from mytable
   where x = 1
   UNION
   Select x, y, z
   from mytable2
   where x = 1
   ) AS X
```

SQL Server needs a reference for the objects in the FROM clause. No alias = no reference
You can see this if we rewrite the query using a CTE

```
WITH myUnion AS
   (
   Select x, y, z
   from mytable
   where x = 1
   UNION
   Select x, y, z
   from mytable2
   where x = 1
  )
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM myUnion
```

Comment: Ughhh - That was so simple Thank you very much. but now I have a similar issue with creating the #temppivot. I tried the same trick but the error is different.
THe colums are dynamic and I think the temp table initially sees the columns as having no headings is this possible

Comment: OK I needed to use ##TempPivot